# Retrieving Facebook Wall posts and storing in Database using .Net 2.0

Tags: facebook, service, .net-2.0, batch-processing

I have searched this question but didn't get / or understood the answer I was seeking.
I have to use .Net 2.0 as our System cant get upgraded. I was thinking of using Facebook Api on the github but that wont work because of the issue of sticking to .Net 2.0

Now my plan is to write a Service or a Batch file that will get the wall posts of the page for my company on facebook and store the results in the SQL database. I have registered my App on the Facebook and got the secret code, etc..

Questions. (I am new to social web sites and retrieving results, but i did study the graph API)

1) Are there any examples for .Net 2.0 to retrieve the wall posts?

2) The messages are returned in the JSON format, Not sure if there is a JSON parser built for .Net 2.0 for handling format. or do i have parse the string use my dataset to store the results i want to.

3) I was using the Open Graph API explorer and it only gives me some resultsets(posts) and in the end the xml has a "paging" which you could use to navigate to more/ older posts.But what if I want to get certain wall posts between some date time, could this be done?

4)I don't want to get an exception to log in to the Facebook account while calling webrequest for Facebook. as this is a service which would run everyday , can i run this service without logging in. ( I know a similar post for without login exist on Stack overflow, but was not able understand in terms of .Net 2.0).

Thanks for reading this. 
Any pointers would be appreciated.

Thanks

RC

I also have to do similar things for Linked In and Twitter.

Comment: Couldn't you create - backend service/"crawler" pushing the results to SQL - at least in .Net 3.5? If necessary located at separated server.

Comment: Yes I can, the front end has to be on .Net 2.0, but the question is on getting posts from facebook.

Comment: ok - create asmx web service in .Net 3.5 - e.g. using facebooksdk.codeplex.com and create frontend web using .Net 2.0..

Comment: I don't have another server and the service or Exe  has to run on the Sharepoint server thats using  .Net 2.0

Comment: Couldn't you: install .Net 3.5 and keep Sharepoint at .Net 2.0 and create other virtual directory or Web Site (with port different from 80) at .Net 3.5? Isn't else virtualization of servers an option?

Comment: No, Its isn't , Personally i am on .Net 4.0, But the place where i work has this server regulated, Upgrading is not an option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) I don't know. But I believe creating extra server is worth the money spent on development.

2) Json is not built-in for .Net 2.0. But you may use: [JsonFx.NET by Stephen M. McKamey](http://jsonfx.net/download/) (Worked with Facebook for me)

3) You may use FQL. For example:

```
SELECT 
post_id, viewer_id, message, app_id, source_id, created_time, updated_time, 
filter_key, attribution, actor_id, target_id, message, app_data, 
action_links, attachment, impressions, comments, likes, privacy, permalink, 
xid, tagged_ids, message_tags, description_tags 
FROM stream 
WHERE 
source_id = me() AND 
created_time > 1323961226 AND 
created_time < 1323961250
```

4) If you request offline_access by login (depending on the solution chosen at point 1) and keep in a safe place your accessToken you should be able to archieve what you described.